# Range based loop declaration must declare a variable

Tags: c++, c++11

```
BYTE Function::Function(long MyInt)
{
    std::vector<int> Red = { 6, 8 };

    for (MyInt : Red)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my function. I want to use MyInt intro for range, but I get a strange error.

I get this error ;
 error: for range

```
declaration must declare a variable
```

What is wrong here? I can't understand.

Comment: Please explain what your function is supposed to do

Comment: `for (MyInt : Red)` what do you expect this to do?

Comment: @SebastianMach It could be the Windows type `BYTE`, which is really just `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>What are you trying to do? This doesn't make sense to me, why would you start a loop to end it immediately by returning?</sub>

Well, you can't use an existing variable in a ranged for loop, you have to declare a new one:

```
for (long myint : Red)
{
    //...
}
```

You could also use the same name `for (long MyInt : Red)`, but that can confuse people into thinking that `MyInt` and `MyInt` are the same variables, which isn't good.